# Design table with similar columns/attributes

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have 2 forms, let's say a product_with_refund_form and product_without_refund_form. In table 1 I have these fields:

- name
- transaction_number
- status
- amount
- cashier

In the 2nd table I have:

- name
- amount
- po_number

My question is, how do you design the table? Do I create each table for both of them or create 1 table with all similar fields, another table for product_with_refund_form that has fields unique to it then another table for product_without_refund_form.

Comment: What role does po_number play?

Comment: Just think of it as a system generated random number.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to work with two similar tables, why not combine the two into a single table.

**Note:**

- The Primary Key "ID" was added to uniquely identify each row with its
  Auto-Incremented value.
- "isRefund" is used as a flag to tell the
  difference between the two forms.  This value could be any single
  character e.g. "y" or "n".
- Since the requirements do not mention an external "cashier" table, I kept this column a varchar field.

---

**Product_Transactions - Field Names**

```
id, name, transaction_number, status, amount, cashier, DateCreated, po_number, isRefund
```

**Table Creation Code**

```
CREATE TABLE Product_Transactions (`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` varchar(100), `status` varchar(10), 'amount' DECIMAL(10,2), 'cashier' varchar(100), 'DateCreated' TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'po_number' varchar(100), 'isRefund' varchar(1), PRIMARY KEY (id))
;
```

Comment: The problem of combining them is that, the fields are still not final, it might be more and if that happens, I'm going to have a lot of empty fields.

Comment: This is mitigated with the use of views.  You only see the values you want to see :)

Comment: With the fields not final as of just yet, you might under/over design the database.  I hope the information provided so far, gives you an idea of where your database table could go.

Comment: True that the views will handle the column/field visibility, but I just don't feel comfortable having empty column values. I'm looking at table inheritance but I'm not sure if it's the best idea for this.

Comment: The relationships between the two tables and their form counterparts are unclear. This needs to be specified so we have a better picture of what is going on under the hood.